# Whats the XPath equivalent to SQL In query?

Tags: xpath, operator-keyword

I would like to know whats the XPath equivalent to SQL In query. Basically in sql i can do this:

```
select * from tbl1 where Id in (1,2,3,4)
```

so i want something similar in XPath/Xsl:

i.e.

```
//*[@id= IN('51417','1121','111')]
```

Please advice

Comment: You really need to say whether you are using XPath 1.0 or 2.0. It makes a vast difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(In XPath 2,) the =  operator always works like in.

I.e. you can use

```
//*[@id = ('51417','1121','111')]
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to write out the options as separate conditions:

```
//*[(@id = '51417') or (@id = '1121') or (@id = '111')]
```

Another, slightly less verbose solution that looks a bit like a hack, though, would be to use the `contains` function:

```
//*[contains('-51417-1121-111-', concat('-', @id, '-'))]
```

Literally, this means you're checking whether the value of the `id` attribute (preceeded and succeeded by a delimiter character) is a substring of `-51417-1121-111-`. Note that I am using a hyphen (`-`) as a delimiter of the allowable values; you can replace that with any character that will not appear in the `id` attribute.